# What does 'mode' mean in this context?

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

The spectrum of an operator $\mathcal{L}$ is the disjoint union of two sets: the point spectrum that consists of all isolated eigenvalues with finite multiplicity and its complement, which we call the essential spectrum.

If part of the essential spectrum lies in the right half-plane, there is typically a continuum of unstable **modes**.

What does **mode** mean here?

Comment: Loosely speaking it means "eigenvector," but the term comes from physics and dates to before a modern understanding of linear algebra. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212142/what-is-a-mode.

Comment: If I understand it right, an eigenvalue can be stable or unstable. Then, I guess, the associated eigenvectors are also called stable or unstable. I can imagine what a continuum of eigenvalues is, but what is a continuum of (unstable) modes/ eigenvectors?